# how to read string of json in pyspark (json string has double double quotation

Tags: json, string, pyspark, tuples

I have a csv file like this:

```
"request"
"{""CustomerId"":""1"",""EffectiveTime"":""2021-07-30T12:00""}"
"{""CustomerId"":""2"",""EffectiveTime"":""2021-07-30T13:00""}"
```

I want to get a pyspark dataframe like this:

```
CustomerId           EffectiveTime
1                     2021-07-30T12:00
2                     2021-07-30T13:00
```

Although pyspark has json_tuple, the csv file request column is not standard json string,
how I can extract CustomerId and EffetiveTime like this?

```
df = df.select(F.json_tuple(F.col("request"), "CustomerId", "EffectiveTime"))
```

I tried above code, and it gets:

```
c0    c1
null  null
null  null
```

Thanks!

Comment: is the format exactly like that? with only 2 columns and exact column names?

Answer (score 1):

I found if I add double quote as escape value

```
df = spark.read.csv(file_path, escape='"', header="true")
```

then I can use json_tuple to extract json string from it.